# Получение значений списка содержащегося в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Как получить все значения списка по ключу `A`, содержащегося в ключе `SOME`?

```
{
  "SOME": [
    {
      "A": ["some text", "some text"],
      "B": ["some text", "some text"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Открыть учебник, прочитать как обращаться к значениям словаря.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте модуль [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/) для поиска ключей и значений в словарях любой глубины / вложенности:

```
import dpath.util as dp   # pip install dpath

In [24]: dp.search(data, "/SOME/**/A")
Out[24]: {'SOME': [{'A': ['some text', 'some text']}]}

In [25]: dp.values(data, "/SOME/**/A")
Out[25]: [['some text', 'some text']]
```